# ROCm installation with Radeon R7 M445 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gpu, amdgpu, gpu-driver, tensorflow

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and made an attempt to install ROCm for GPU computing on AMD Radeon R7 M445. I need it to use GPU capabilities of tensorflow. I followed this tutorial: Install AMD ROCm — ROCm Documentation 1.0.0 documentation. Not sure if this GPU is supported by ROCm because I saw in several places differently.

ROCm version is 3.7.0-20.

Linux Kernel version is 5.4.0-42-generic.

When running the command `sudo apt install rocm-dkms`, the output on terminal was:

```
Secure Boot not enabled on this system. Done. Forcing installation of amdgpu

 

amdgpu.ko: Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/updates/dkms/

 

amdttm.ko: Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/updates/dkms/

 

amdkcl.ko: Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/updates/dkms/

 

amd-sched.ko: Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/updates/dkms/

 

depmod....

 

Backing up initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic to /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic.old-dkms Making new initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic (If next boot fails, revert to initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic.old-dkms image) update-initramfs......

 

DKMS: install completed.
```

The output I get when running `opt/rocm/bin/rocminfo` is :

```
ROCk module is loaded
Able to open /dev/kfd read-write
=====================    
HSA System Attributes    
=====================    
Runtime Version:         1.1
System Timestamp Freq.:  1000.000000MHz
Sig. Max Wait Duration:  18446744073709551615 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) (timestamp count)
Machine Model:           LARGE                              
System Endianness:       LITTLE                             

 

==========               
HSA Agents               
==========               
*******                  
Agent 1                  
*******                  
  Name:                    Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
  Uuid:                    CPU-XX                             
  Marketing Name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
  Vendor Name:             CPU                                
  Feature:                 None specified                     
  Profile:                 FULL_PROFILE                       
  Float Round Mode:        NEAR                               
  Max Queue Number:        0(0x0)                             
  Queue Min Size:          0(0x0)                             
  Queue Max Size:          0(0x0)                             
  Queue Type:              MULTI                              
  Node:                    0                                  
  Device Type:             CPU                                
  Cache Info:              
    L1:                      32768(0x8000) KB                   
  Chip ID:                 0(0x0)                             
  Cacheline Size:          64(0x40)                           
  Max Clock Freq. (MHz):   3500                               
  BDFID:                   0                                  
  Internal Node ID:        0                                  
  Compute Unit:            4                                  
  SIMDs per CU:            0                                  
  Shader Engines:          0                                  
  Shader Arrs. per Eng.:   0                                  
  WatchPts on Addr. Ranges:1                                  
  Features:                None
  Pool Info:               
    Pool 1                   
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: KERNARG, FINE GRAINED
      Size:                    16294032(0xf8a090) KB              
      Allocatable:             TRUE                               
      Alloc Granule:           4KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB                                
      Accessible by all:       TRUE                               
    Pool 2                   
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: COARSE GRAINED      
      Size:                    16294032(0xf8a090) KB              
      Allocatable:             TRUE                               
      Alloc Granule:           4KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB                                
      Accessible by all:       TRUE                               
  ISA Info:                
    N/A                      
*** Done ***
```

And for `/opt/rocm/opencl/bin/clinfo` I get:

```
Number of platforms:                 1
  Platform Profile:                 FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:                 OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (3182.0)
  Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor:                 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Extensions:                 cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback


  Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices:                 0
```

Do you have any idea what is the problem? I tried many things I saw online, and updated everything I can think of or find (OpenCL, OpenGL). The installed driver for the GPU is "amdgpu".

Answer (score 1):

Coworker has laptop with similar dGPU to R7 M445 (I think M255) and it works really bad. It was not even usable in 18.04. Now with 20.04 he can use it, but it's not much better than intel iGPU.

This is for open source AMDGPU (non-pro) driver. The AMDGPU-PRO driver was working with 16.04.x (x is not the newest), and it did support some OpenCL iirc)

Regarding ROCm - you are out of luck. Only few cards are actually supported - mainly Polaris (e.g. RX 580) and desktop Vega (e.g. Vega 64). Older cards (e.g. R9 270) are not supported at all. dGPUs are not supported (like your M445) It's quite a mess.